# Laravel: How to run multiple schedules at the same time for multiple finger machines?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, schedule, cron-task

I have multiple finger machines. I want to run multiple schedules at the same time for multiple finger machines. How can I run multiple schedules for it? The below code is to run for one finger machine.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $pagi = WaktuMesin::select('pagi')->first();
    $tarik_pagi = explode('-', $pagi['pagi']);
    $tarik_pagi = $tarik_pagi[1];
    $tarik_pagi_kehadiran = date('H:i', strtotime($tarik_pagi. ' +3 minutes'));
   
    $siang = WaktuMesin::select('siang')->first();
    $tarik_siang = explode('-', $siang['siang']);
    $tarik_siang = $tarik_siang[1];
    $tarik_siang_kehadiran = date('H:i', strtotime($tarik_siang. ' +3 minutes'));

    $sore = WaktuMesin::select('sore')->first();
    $tarik_sore = explode('-', $sore['sore']);
    $tarik_sore = $tarik_sore[1];
    $tarik_sore_kehadiran = date('H:i', strtotime($tarik_sore. ' +3 minutes'));
    
    $schedule->command('tarik:absen')->everyMinute()->timezone('Asia/Jakarta');
    $schedule->command('send:wa')->everyMinute()->timezone('Asia/Jakarta');
    $schedule->command('tarik:pagi')->dailyAt($tarik_pagi_kehadiran)->timezone('Asia/Jakarta');
    $schedule->command('tarik:siang')->dailyAt($tarik_siang_kehadiran)->timezone('Asia/Jakarta');
    $schedule->command('tarik:sore')->dailyAt($tarik_sore_kehadiran)->timezone('Asia/Jakarta');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you could wrap your code from above (for each finger machine) in a closure like:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
   //code for finger 1 goes here
})->daily();
```

sure not the best softwaredesign, but you could go this way for each finger machine.

I´d would recommend to invoke each finger machine function from a dedicated class like "Class FingerMachines" to keep your code clean.

```
$schedule->call(fn () => FingerMachines::runFirstMachine())
    ->name('finger-machine-1')
    ->weekly();
```

If you go the closure way, you should give your closures a name like:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
       //code for finger 1 goes here
    })->daily()->name('finger-machine-1');
```